# segmentation fault on std::regex and when multi-threading using C++ driver

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb, c++11, segmentation-fault

I fixed the linker error yesterday and run this project on Ubuntu. It throws Segmentation fault. I try to debug it using gdb, but it didn't work.This code is stable (works great) under Mac OS X with Xcode. 
Here is the up-to-date code of this project. It should compile using g++-4.9. 
**Links of mine source code:** https://github.com/DengYiping/Shuoshuo_crawler

If you are interested in crawling Tencent's Shuoshuo, one of the largest social network, please help me refine this project.

When execute it without multi-threading(enter 1 when ask you to enter number of threads), it throws segmentation fault on type `std::regex_traits<char>` **after running it for around 20 second**

Here is the message in gdb:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./qq_crawler'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000043cbf8 in std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >* std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*, std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*>(std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*, std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*, std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*) ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000043cbf8 in std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >* std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*, std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*>(std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*, std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*, std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >*) ()
#1  0x000000000043891c in std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<std::__detail::_AnyMatcher<std::regex_traits<char>, false, true, true> >::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::integral_constant<bool, false>) ()
#2  0x0000000000434c4e in std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<std::__detail::_AnyMatcher<std::regex_traits<char>, false, true, true> >::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation) ()
#3  0x00000000004288a4 in std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<std::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, std::regex_traits<char>, false>::_M_lookahead(std::__detail::_State<std::regex_traits<char> >) ()
#4  0x0000000000426036 in void std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<std::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, std::regex_traits<char>, true>::_M_dfs<true>(long) ()
#5  0x0000000000425bf2 in void std::__detail::_Executor<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<std::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, std::regex_traits<char>, false>::_M_dfs<false>(long) ()
```

I try to fix it by removing the `std::move` on `std::match substrings` when I call `substrings[1]`. I change it from`json_string = std::move(substrings[1])` to `json_string = substrings[1];`. I know it may lead to extra memory use and possible call of `memcpy()` when assign directly. **But the error remains the same!!!**

The weird thing is that when I open multi-threading, it throws a different message on boost library, on which mongo-cxx-driver relies. **This time it throws segmentation fault immediately:**

```
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffebfff700 (LWP 7268)]
0x00007ffff7bd1150 in std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<void const*, std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node>, std::__1::less<void const*>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node>, void*>*) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bd1150 in std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<void const*, std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node>, std::__1::less<void const*>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<void const*, boost::detail::tss_data_node>, void*>*) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0
#1  0x00007ffff7bc4383 in boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()
    () from /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0
#2  0x00000000004c6367 in ~thread_data (this=0x27b1930, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90
#3  boost::detail::thread_data<std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (mongo::BackgroundJob::*)()> (mongo::BackgroundJob*)> >::~thread_data() (this=0x27b1930, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90
#4  0x00007ffff7bc4a6e in boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_proxy(void*) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0
#5  0x00007ffff700b182 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffebfff700)
    at pthread_create.c:312
#6  0x00007ffff6b2147d in clone ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm about 99% sure that you are mixing libc++ and libstdc++ here, based on the presence and absence of __1 in the symbol names. What standard library is your application linked to? Your build of boost? The C++ driver?

In general the C++ driver, the boost library, and your application, must all use the same C++ runtime library and language standard:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#scons-options-when-compiling-the-c-driver

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to recompile the Boost Library. I think I compile Boost Library using libc++.

Comment: You can also compile the C++ driver against libc++ by building with the -libc++ flag.

Comment: @ScottDeng FYI you should probably throw me an upvote and accept my answer, if you found it helpful.

Comment: Seems like it isn't the problem of linking boost library. I try couple times to recompile the entire boost library, the mongo-driver and my source code with c++11 and libstdc++(default choice of g++). I even remove llvm and clang.  It is obvious the problem remains the same. I am still digging and trying to fix this problem. If I cannot find the problem, I will wait for your C++11 driver! It is good to see people like you helping people. Thank you! @acm

Comment: @ScottDeng Are you 100% sure that all three pieces (boost, the mongo C++ driver, and your application) are now compiled with the same C++ language version and the same standard library? You can confirm the latter at least with ldd or readelf. If so, are you sure that you are getting exactly the same error now as before? If so, I think you should post a minimal example containing directly compilable code that demonstrates the problem and I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes. Since I deleted Clang, and I uninstalled the old version of gcc. I compiled every pieces with c++11 on. It should work. However, there is something wrong in the program. I'm currently a high school student. I will gives you details when I got home. The source code is here https://github.com/DengYiping/Shuoshuo_crawler. It should compile(if not, just modified the Makefile. My programs only depends on libjsoncpp and STL). I tries to reproduce the problem in Xcode. However, it works great on Xcode.@acm

Comment: enter three number for the first three in the program, and enter a number greater than 1 for the last one. I will write a test soon for this project. Since I am in high school, I wouldn't be able to do it. @acm Thanks!

Comment: Thnak you for replying. Although this is not a problem of MongoDB driver, thank you so much. std::regex under libc++ is not trustworthy. I change the domain to boost::regex and it works great. Simple std problems. By the way, how's the new driver going?

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. The new driver is coming along well. Look for an 0.3.0 release in the next week or so, and then we will start releasing RCs leading up to a mid-December release. Or at least that is the plan :)